# calculate current page base on offset and total item

Tags: javascript, pagination

I'm using 2 different module to do pagination, the backend module didn't use offset, it need `page`. So I have to be able to pass a page param for it.

I'm stuck figuring how can I calculate the **page base on offset and total item.**

This is the formula for offset

`offset = (page - 1) * total + 1`

How about find `page`?

Comment: Did you get it working?

Answer (score 0):

You say you have this formula and need to write it in terms of `page`:

```
offset = (page - 1) * total + 1
```

With a few transformations you can get it:

```
offset - 1 = (page - 1) * total
(offset - 1) / total = page - 1
(offset - 1) / total + 1 = page
```

I.e., the final formula is:

```
page = (offset - 1) / total + 1
```

Comment: this will have decimal

Comment: Then cast it to int by rounding up - `page = page.ceil()`.